# Retornar os 5 primeiros itens de uma lista em Python

Tags: python

Dada a lista abaixo:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Existe uma maneira rápida de pegar os 5 primeiros itens dessa lista? Algo como `list.get_first(5)`?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o intuito da pergunta, mas ao meu ver a proposta é exatamente a mesma que a que coloquei como duplicada. Se discordar, por favor comente argumentando com as diferenças e eu reavalio o fechamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com [este tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) da documentação do Python, pode-se usar a funcionalidade de "slicing" das listas, fazendo:

```
first_5 = array[:5]
```

Que vai retornar a seguinte lista:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Pode-se ainda usar os índices da lista, seguindo a sintaxe:

```
array[start:stop:step]
```

Para exemplificar, podemos pegar do número 2 até o 10 pulando de 2 em 2 (incluindo o 2 e excluindo o 10) fazendo:

```
list[1:9:2]
```

O que resultaria em:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```